# Is the "Cirkel van 8" problem approach known as "Figure of 8" in English? Is it a well-known approach for improving soft-skills of employees?

Tags: company-culture

At the company we get coaching every month about how to deal with difficulties. Although I personally want to focus on the technical stuff, the idea of "the circle of 8" impresses me. However, when I look for this on the internet, it seems that "the circle of 8" does not exist in English. Could somebody confirm this? What is the real name of the model?

Cirkel van 8 (Dutch). Literal English translation "Circle of 8" If one queries for this on Google, only some Marvel and other fictive stuff is returned, but when one queries for "cirkel van 8" a lot pictures are shown, like these:

[image]

https://www.pentascope.nl/kikken-dippen/cirkel-van-8/
Translation (from Google):

"Challenging situations"

- Top: "Looking for opportunities"

  1. "Accept the situation"
  2. "Focus on here & now"
  3. "Feeling: I have influence"
  4. "Searching for power sources"
  5. "Solution-oriented behavior"
- Bottom: "Thinking in trouble"

  1. "Resist the situation"
  2. "Compare and judge"
  3. "Feeling: I have no influence"
  4. "Power to others"
  5. "Ineffective behavior"
  6. "Strengthened..."

The circle of 8 is a model for dealing with difficult situations. It is basically about taking action yourself rather than complaining and doing nothing to improve a situation.

Comment: An English translation would be appreciated.

Comment: But what's your actual question? "Does this thing exist" isn't really a question.

Comment: Possibly Dudley Weeks' well-known 8 steps of conflict resolution? https://www.conovercompany.com/conflict-resolution-8-steps-for-resolving-conflicts/

Comment: The answer seems to be “no”, but it’s very hard to prove a negative. Given all the buzzword-driven presentations I’ve seen in my career, if it was a thing, I think I’d have heard of it it existed.

Comment: The English translation is much more likely to be “figure of eight”

Comment: @bishop although there's 11 steps in this figure of 8

Comment: I've seem the similar train of thought presented in A LOT of different ways and models, the specifics depend a lot on the business area is being presented to. One of the most common ones is "celebrate the red" in Lean Manufacturing, and the "growth mindset x fixed mindset" in adult learning. This exact model I've never seen before. (And I'll be using it. Beter goed gestolen dan slecht bedacht :P)

Comment: This has been asked atleast once already surely you’ve realized that it is not common in the english speaking world